# How can I download an app apk/ipa from Firebase App Distribution using their CLI or curl?

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution

My organizations uses Google Firebase to distribute apps to manual testers. For automated testing, we need access to the app apk/ipa directly to pass the local path to appium.

I see under App Distribution / Releases in Firebase Console that there is now a "Download" button which does what I need. However, is there a corresponding Firebase CLI endpoint or a way I could even just use curl to grab the needed build from firebase and download it?

Answer (score 0):

While Firebase App Distribution does have a REST API, as far as I can tell that API only has support for [uploading and distributing releases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/app-distribution/rest/v1/projects.apps.releases/distribute) and [managing testers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/app-distribution/rest/v1/projects.testers). There doesn't seem to be a way to get a release binary through any API.

It's a reasonable wish though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it.

Comment: Thanks, i have filed a feature request.